# I want to buy a fixed gear bike. Which one should I buy?

Tags: fixed-gear

This is my first time posting here. I'm 15 years old, I want to buy a fixed gear bike to get to school, job and metro. I live in Montreal,Canada if you wonder... A fixie would be perfect since Montreal doesn't really have hills and my way to school and job is just flat ground. So I asked my friend who works at a bike shop if he had something to recommend and he actually told me he was selling two.

The first one is a Giant Bowery 2012, State Bicycle Co wheels, Thickslick tires, BREV handlebars and the pedals are just standard.
http://postimg.org/image/8tsa3icbh/

The second one is a Miyata 618GT, State Bicycle Co wheels, Thickslick tires, GIX (not sure what this means) drop bars and Ruben Tec pedals.
http://postimg.org/image/skbez2sx5/

now my question is : which one should I choose and what price should I pay for it!
Thanks alot !

Comment: Whichever you buy, please don't ride brakeless.  Get at least a front brake installed, if not front and back.  Not only will it save you money on tires, they work much better for emergency braking.

Comment: Since it would be my first time riding a fixie, I was going to put at least a front brake.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Unfortunately Stack Exchange sites are not well suited to specific product recommendations due to the subjective nature of replies. It's better to describe the type of riding you're going to do and ask for the type of features you should look for. Here's some more on the reasoning behind that: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/276/do-we-go-shopping

Answer (score 1):

Which bike someone should buy always depends on personal preferences, so it is quite difficult to take the decision for you and tell you which one you should buy. Different people have different priorities when buying a bike, someone maybe prefers a certain size of tires, for others the price is an important factor, etc.

You could ask in the bike shop if you can try them both out for a short ride, and you will see which one you like more.

Comment: +1 Try before you buy. In fact try as many as you can! Make notes in case you forget.

Answer (score 0):

The Giant has a better saddle and a better handlebar/stem;

The Myiata has pedals with footstraps already;

Depending of your height, the Giant's frame is relatively small (short seat tube), while the Myiata is much taller;

The Myiata looks like an old road bike converted to fixie, while the Giant looks like a track (velodrome) oriented bike. Surprisingly, this makes the Myiata a better bike to ride in the street, since it would be easier to fit some brakes, and it is designed to stand rougher terrain better.

If I could choose, I would swap the saddle and the handlebar/stem between bikes, and keep the Myiata with a front brake.

In the end, these facts are NOT enough for you to make the choice, but I hope they help!